# Store as variable vs without

Tags: c#, performance, variables, memory-management

For these two methods below, is there any difference at all? Put aside code readability, will `Method1` consume less memory, while `Method2` perform faster?

In general, which one should I *always* use?

```
    public void Method1(string userInput)
    {
        if (userInput.ToLower().Replace(" ", "") == "optiona")
        {

        }

        else if (userInput.ToLower().Replace(" ", "") == "optionb")
        {

        }

        else
        {

        }
    }

    public void Method2(string userInput)
    {
        string modifiedInput = userInput.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");

        if (modifiedInput == "optiona")
        {

        }
        else if (modifiedInput == "optionb")
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: In `Method2` you "save" one call to `userInput.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");`. It doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I prefer `method2` as it you remove the necessity of repeating the operation over and over.

But in the end it is a micro-optimisation. Since a new string is created by the operations, you will probably find that `method2` is SLIGHTLY better.

But in the end, if you want to find which of 2 horses is fastest, race them.

Answer (score 0):

If the user input is "optionb", method2 will be better, if the user input is "optiona" more than average, method1 and method2 will be have no recognizable difference.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer method2 as well. But not for the performance reason as @David has mentioned.

Method2 is easier to read.

Using a temporary variable adds an extra line to the method. This extra line reflects the extra step of operation that is really happening in your method.

Especially when you give this variable a meaningful name "modifiedInput", other programmers will have a easier time understanding what your method is doing.

Easier to understand code means better maintainability.